# list locally installed maven dependencies

Tags: maven, local

on my development machine i'm actively working on perhaps 20 inter-dependent maven projects, most of which get published to ossrh from time to time, and i also depend on many other projects from maven central

i'd like to list the dependencies that have been installed locally as opposed to those that have been downloaded from a repository. i'm aware that `mvn -U` will check remote repositories for snapshot dependencies, but in many cases my versions aren't -SNAPSHOT

is there a way to tell which dependencies have been installed locally ?

Comment: Simple answer: No...

Comment: The local repository has files of name `_remote.repositories` in the artifact directories. They are not a public interface, but they might allow you to reverse engineer where the artifacts came from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The local repository has files of name _remote.repositories in the artifact directories. They are not a public interface, but they might allow you to reverse engineer where the artifacts came from.

@nqzero came up with the expression

```
mvn dependency:list -DoutputAbsoluteArtifactFilename -DoutputFile=/dev/fd/2 2>&1 1>/dev/null | grep -o "/.*/" | xargs -Ixxx grep -L "jar>central=$" xxx_remote.repositories
```

that actually does the trick.

Comment: appending `| grep -o ".*/"` to the end of that line gives the artifact directories instead of the `_remote.repositories` files, which i guess might be more generally useful. thanks for the hint - got me exactly what i needed